# Randomly replace numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

How would I go about replacing random numbers in an array with an X as i want to randomly not display some numbers when printing the array.

so for example i have an array coded like this:

```
  void main()
{

    int Array[3][3];
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
        {
            if (col == 0)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 1st col

            else if (col == 1)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 2nd col

            else if (col == 2)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 3rd col

        }// end col for

        printf("\n");

    }// end row for 

    //print
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", Array[row][col]);

        }// end col for

        printf("\n");

    }// end row for ptinting the array
    _getch();
}
```

example output from this is:

1  7  4

0  9  4

8  8  2

I want to randomly replace numbers inside this array with an X like this:

1  x  4

x  9  4

8  8  x

Thanks.

Comment: X is not a number.  Set the value to some known, out-of-range value like -1.  Then check for that, and print X .

Comment: The Number can be a zero as in the final code the range will be between 1 and 90. How do I randomly select the numbers inside the array to change to the designated value (zero) though?

Comment: It is not enough to say "randomly". You need also to decide, at least, randomly with what expectation? 20% of elements? 50%? 90%? Once you decide that, you will have *many* answers below, and good ones, trust me.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been more clear. 4 out of the 9 numbers would need to be changed. So ~44%

Comment: In pseudo-code: `if (rand() % 9 < 4) printf Array[row][col] else printf "X"`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: That's only leaving me with 2 numbers not changed to X. 1 and 4 in the top row. Everything else is now X

Comment: Yes, this is random, 44% is the long-run expectation. In each run of the program change the seed (i.e. `srand(time(NULL));`  place that at the very beginning of `main`) and you will get different results.

Comment: Ok yeah I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First in the first code no need for the condition "if" this will create a big latency in term of exécution beside the fact that there is no need for condition.

Now for having random x juste create a loop that step throw row element and for each incrémentation you call the random function inside this loop and the returned random value must be a value between 0 and 2 so create a while that check the returned value and the condition to go outside the while is that returned value is between 0 and 2 once done this value will be your col index where you are going to place the x

Comment: Yeah sorry the "if" is there because in the final code the columns have to have ranges. So 1st column is between 1 - 10 , 2nd is between 11 - 20 an so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main() {
    int Array[3][3];
    int row,col;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(row=0;row<3;row++)
        for(col=0;col<3;col++)
            Array[row][col] = rand() % 10;

    for(row=0;row<3;row++) {
        for(col=0;col<3;col++)
            if(rand() % 2)
                printf("%d ", Array[row][col]);
            else
                printf("X ");
        printf("\n");
    }        
}
```

Comment: You provided what looks like a complete program, but you forgot to set the values in `Array`. Also, I get the idea OP doesn't want to *overwrite* them, but merely "not show". ..Perhaps you can make them negative to indicate this? (Just a thought.) Also, please loose the `getch` at the end. (*Not* a mere thought.)

Comment: You can overwrite them or just not show them either way is fine. I just thought not showing them would be easier to do. You need _getch(); to keep the window open, don't you? Otherwise the program just runs and closes?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Not showing them is easier. I see no difference between _getch() and getch(), but you can edit it of course. I've edited the code so it looks better now.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to A.S.H this is what I've done:

```
void main()
{

    int Array[3][3];
    int row, col;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
        {
            if (col == 0)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 1st col

            else if (col == 1)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 2nd col

            else if (col == 2)
            {
                Array[row][col] = (rand() % 10);

            }//end of 3rd col

        }// end col for

        printf("\n");

    }// end row for 

    //print
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {


            if (rand() % 9 < 4)
            {
                printf("%d \t", Array[row][col]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s \t", "X");
            }
        }// end col for

        printf("\n");

    }// end row for ptinting the array
    _getch();
}
```

Getting print outs like:

x  x  9

x  x  5

3  0  x

Too many of the numbers seem to be x's at the moment but that might be a mistake I've made somewhere that I can't see yet.